# Is it possible to send notifications to users who installed the Progressive Web App

Tags: jekyll, progressive-web-apps

I configured **pwa** feature in my [site](https://news.justinechacko.in/) 
 How can I send notifications to users?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I edited the question. Is this fine?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a [Web API for notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API), but support is limited to desktop and Android. Hence, your iOS users will not receive them.

Also, you do need to ask for permission from the users of your app. You can limit the notifications to only installed PWAs by activating notifications in the `onappinstalled` event, but I do not know why you would want to do that.

Comment: Thanks @TmKVU. I Don't want to limit notification to installed app, I was asking whether push notifications are only available for installed app? I am new to JavaScript, so I can't follow the full instructions there. Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) link is same as you give me? Also is [this](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.XRYQgfDhU0N) link is applicable in my case?

Comment: @JustineChacko No they are not only available for installed applications, but they are also available if the browser supports the feature. Those links seem like a good starting point! Good luck :)